# ng-repeat in combination with ng-init

Tags: angularjs

Controllers loads $scope.shops on init already. Async with defer and promise etc.. I create a panel for each shop there is available. Then I'd like to add columns for each item.

I have a method in controller getItemsPerShop(item) which is also async etc.. I currently get two panels (there are two shops), but the items are the same.. probably cause of the async issue and the $scope.items not getting downloaded fast enough, how would I go about solving this.

```
   <div ng-repeat="shop in shops">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">shop {{shop}}</div>
            <table class="table">
                <thead ng-init="getItemsPershop(shop)">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Number</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody ng-repeat="item in items"> 
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">{{item.nr}}</th>
                        <td>{{item.desc}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It's like a nested situation where the each panel need to load it's rows.

Comment: Is it just me or you didn't clarified your problem properly?

Comment: The items listed in the shop panels are the same while they shouldn't be because the ng-init should load the unique items for each panel. But I now see my way of working is impossible because I bind the items of each panel to the same variable.

Comment: i will do all the query in the controller side. the controller should return the full data and the view just  display them.
why you don't put getItemsPershop(shop) in the controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your template looks, you have one array `items` in your scope. However, you need to nest it in the shop, otherwise you can't distinguish them.

In the end it will look like this:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="item in shop.items"> 
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{item.nr}}</th>
        <td>{{item.desc}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

As pointed out in another answer you can assign the items to a field `items` in a scope local to the current shop. However I would discourage you from doing so. From [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit):

> There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit, such as for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below; and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these few cases, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

In angular you are supposed to init a model in your controller and render it via a template. Mixing these two makes your code harder to understand, test, and maintain.

Comment: Going to accept this because made me think about structure

Answer (score 2):

I will go for making `getItemsPershop()` in controller.

Did you forget the `items =` in `ng-init`?

```
<div ng-repeat="shop in shops">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">shop {{shop}}</div>
            <table class="table">
                <!-- forgot "items =" ? -->
                <thead ng-init="items = getItemsPershop(shop)">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Number</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody ng-repeat="item in items"> 
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">{{item.nr}}</th>
                        <td>{{item.desc}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
</div>
```